# Tackling recursion while using Scala Futures

Tags: scala, recursion, async-await, future, scala.js

In my working code is recursion involved. I try to avoid this, because the recursion could be too deep if a predicate don't hold.

```
case class Chan[T]() {
  private var promise: Promise[T] = Promise[T]()

  /** Binds a handler with the "write" in casu update() */
  def this(handler: (T => Unit) => Unit) {
    this
    handler(update)
  }

  def filter(p: (T) => Boolean): Future[T] = {
     apply().flatMap(value => if (p(value)) Future(value) else filter(p))
  }

  def apply(): Future[T] = {
    promise = Promise[T]()
    promise.future
  }

  def update(t: T): Unit = {
    if (!promise.isCompleted) promise.success(t)    
  }
}
```

The problem lays in the `filter` method. When the predicate is not met, `filter` will be called again, hunting for an event which is conform the parameter. By that the stack will be filled, ahead for a StackOverflow :-).

How can the code refactored, in a loop or tail recursive calls, avoiding excessive stack usage?

Comment: Would you mind to explain what this code is doing? Your usage of `apply` and fact that you have a var in a clearly concurrent environment looks rather exotic to me. I'm asking because I suspect that your issue is not a recursion, but rather the way you're trying to solve the underlying problem.

Comment: To me it's rather unclear what you are trying to achieve. 
Your code might suggest you're rather dealing with a continuous stream of updates, so I'd suggest looking into reactive streams (akka streams). If I understood you correctly your filter operation would become a simple filter on a reactive stream!

Comment: I can image that on the first sight this code looks weird, but it's an implementation of a single item [channel] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_(programming)) primitive in a async/await Scala.JS application. As you know JavaScript is single threaded and null is a JS primitive. It works good and I am asking for the elimination of the recursion.Thank you in advance for the collaboration.

Comment: ok, I think I got it now. remove the apply method and the shared mutable promise var, create the promise inside your filter and store it together with the filter predicate as a pair in a list / map. every time you receive an update you can now check if one off the registered predicates is true and complete the promise for these.

Answer (score 1):

So here's the solution as suggested above.
I hope that fits your purpose:

```
case class Chan[T]() {

  private var pendingFilters: List[(T => Boolean, Promise[T])] = List.empty

  /** Binds a handler with the "write" in casu update() */
  def this(handler: (T => Unit) => Unit) {
    this
    handler(update)
  }

  def filter(p: (T) => Boolean): Future[T] = {
    val promise = Promise[T]()
    // add both the predicate and the promise to your pending filters
    synchronized(pendingFilters = p -> promise :: pendingFilters)
    promise.future
  }

  def update(t: T): Unit = {
    synchronized {
      // partition your pending filters into completed and uncompleted ones
      val (completed, pending) = pendingFilters.partition(_._1(t))
      pendingFilters = pending
      completed
    }.foreach{ case (_, promise) =>
      // and finally complete the promises
      promise.trySuccess(t)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. It's an interesting solution. I will try it soon. But first I want to do some tests if my `flatMap` clause will consume so eagerly the stack. I think your solution does almost the same, creating a `Future` with a anonymous function to test the result when it is available.

Comment: Conceptually the solutions are actually totally different. The way you are using flatMap you're building up stack with every update call! Moreover the solution in your question won't be able to support multiple filters. E.g. if you add a second filter before the first one is satisfied/completed, you would be starving the first promise as it can't ever be completed - there's no reference to it anymore that is visible to your update method!

Comment: Hmm.  Is synchronized even implemented in Scala.js?  This is a fundamentally single-threaded, blocking-not-possible environment, so synchronize seems a bit irrelevant...

Comment: Yeah, its really working. [Github repository](https://github.com/SeriousSoftware/ScalaJS-Asynchronous-Workflows). Scala.js is with async/await single-threaded, non-blocking with a lots of possibilities. Most of the Scala libraries run on this platform too. It's a hidden gem.

Comment: Interesting -- I played a bit with async/await way back when (a year ago -- an eternity by Scala.js standards), but I was having problems getting my utest tests working and drifted back towards just using straight Future composition.  I'll have to look into this; thanks...